# Scala Args Parsing

Tags: scala, command-line-arguments

Why does

```
println("Hello, " + args(0) + "!")
```

work when I run scala nomain.scala but

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: List[String]) {
    println("Hello, " + args(0) + "!")
  }
}
```

Gives me the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Main.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:94)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.run$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:90)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:129)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run(ObjectRunner.scala:22)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run$(ObjectRunner.scala:21)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:29)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch$(ObjectRunner.scala:28)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.runCompiled(ScriptRunner.scala:170)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.$anonfun$runScript$1(ScriptRunner.scala:187)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.$anonfun$runScript$1$adapted(ScriptRunner.scala:187)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.$anonfun$withCompiledScript$2(ScriptRunner.scala:156)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.scala:124)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.runScriptAndCatch(ScriptRunner.scala:200)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:63)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:88)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:99)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:104)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

when I run scala helloworld.scala

I tried adding some statements like `if (args.size > 0)` but that also gives me errors. I am wondering what I am doing wrong here. I am wondering how I would check to see if the list has something in it and also how to directly print args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = ???
```

should be instead of

```
def main(args: List[String]): Unit = ???
```

Comment: Yeah I took a few steps backwards and realized this. But, my follow up is how do I check if args has a length of 1 to start the program?

Comment: @SamBean execute `scalac HelloWorld.scala` and then `scala HelloWorld World`.

Comment: You can add `if (args.length > 0)` or `if (args.size > 0)` if you need.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this to check if the first argument exists:

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if(args.headOption.isDefined) {
      println("Hello, " + args(0) + "!")
    } else {
      println("There is no first argument")
    }
  }
}
```